# Make a multiple query to build a table with some data summary

Tags: php, mysql, tabular

I have the following MYSQL tables:

```
pupils:

id_pupil
name
surname
email
user
pass
level
class

califications:

id_calification
calification
date
time
subject
id_pupil
id_user
id_trimester
type_calification (misses, delayes or attitude)

incidents:

id_incidents
date
time
type_incident
comments
id_pupil
id_user
subject
id_trimester

trimesters:

id_trimester
starting_date
ending_date

timetables:

id_timetable
subject
date
time
level
class
id_user

users:

id_user
name
surname
email
user
pass
type_user
```

and I would like to build a summary table with the next information:

[image]

I don´t know how to build this table with multiple queries. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is there a language in which 'calification' is a word?

Comment: I don´t understand what you mean. I´m Spanish and is Calificación/Nota

Comment: OK - That's 'qualification' in English ;-) So, next question - what have you tried? And consider providing proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: Sorry i don´t understand you... :(

Comment: Do you mean this page? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: But i don´t kknow how i build the query to do i want to do